# same domain object produces different filed names in different settings (jsonview)?

Tags: json, jackson

we are using jackson 2.6.3 in our spring boot project. The domain object needs to be serialized to the user of this app and another internal service. How can I have a field, say 'myField', serialized to 'public_field' for users of our app, and 'internalSvcField' when serialized to the internal service? Eg

```
myField = "value";
```

when serialized in different situations,

```
{..."public_field": "value"...}
```

and

```
{..."internalSvcField": "value"...}
```

any helps/hints are deeply appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JsonViews for this. It's a feature of Jackson nicely integrated into spring. Check an in-depth tutorial about it here:

https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring

Comment: I tried JsonView. But you cannot define 2 different names for the same field. Also, one view is completely contained within another view, so it is not possible to have fields only in each view, but not in the other :(